# Midpoint of a set as Mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, contest-math

Given a set **of an odd number of terms**:

$x = \{a, b, c, ..., \}$

Consisting of $n$ elements. How is the midpoint of the set. **A proof and explanation would be helpful**:

> $$\frac{a + b + c + ... }{n} = \overline{x}$$

I just need some hints to begin with.

> Why is the average of the set of an odd number of terms is equal to the midpoint of the set? Consider (3, 4, 5), the average = 4, and the midpoint is also =4. Why is this true in a general case?

Comment: What are you asking? When the median is the mean?

Comment: Your question needs clarification. What are you asking? You are using $n$ as both an element of the set and the number of elements of the set.

Comment: Are you asking for the average?

Comment: Question has been edited, sorry for the inclarity

Comment: The question still is not clear. It still looks like you are asking if the median is the mean--which is not true in general.

Comment: @Amad27 I edited your post , I guess you meant $4$ instead of $3$ for the mean and the midpoint

Comment: Do you intend an odd number of consecutive integers?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in the general case.

Counter example, $(3,7,10)$ , now the average is $\large{\frac{3 + 7 + 10 = 20}{3} = 6.6667}$ , However, the midpoint is $7 \neq 6.6667$ and so it is not true in this case.

I guess it holds for successive numbers for example, $(6,7,8)$ or in general $(a,a+1,a+2) (3 \space terms)$ or $(a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4) (5 \space terms)$ .... etc

Comment: The median is the mean for a odd number of terms of an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: @TimThayer, a proof for that? (+1)